# Is it possible to identify the rune type through reflection in Golang?

Tags: go

In Go, When I do `reflect.TypeOf(r)`, where `r` is a rune variable, I get the type int32. When I do a type switch, I cannot differentiate int32 from rune. The docs say:

> rune is an alias for int32 and is equivalent to int32 in all ways. It is used, by convention, to distinguish character values from integer values.

Before giving, I just wanted to ask here: is there any way whatsoever to differentiate rune from int32 through reflection in Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [alias](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) binds an identifier to a type. The identifier `rune` refers to the same type as `int32`.

The identifier used to refer to a type in source code is not available at runtime through reflection or any other API.

Answer (score 4):

The Go language does not provide any built-in mechanism to distinguish between them using reflection. The `reflect.TypeOf()` function returns the underlying type, which in this case is `int32`, regardless of whether the variable is declared as `rune` or `int32`.
So if you need to differentiate between `rune` and `int32`, you will need to use other means, such as conditional checks to handle them differently in your code.

Comment: Yes my bad, type assertion does not make distinction.

Comment: So it seems there is no way at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, NubDev! Many or most of your 23 answers in the last two weeks appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.